# How do I offset an image with absolute position in css?

Tags: html, css

I need to recreate this -

[image: Required design]

but the nearest I can get is this

[image: Best I can do]

If I try and apply left/right value to the image, it goes all over the place. I know it has something to do with overflow, but I cannot work out what exactly. I tried it as a background-image rather than actually inserting an image, but I need that transparency. Here's the code. Where am I going wrong? I should add it still needs to be responsive.

```css
.quotebox {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 70%;
}

.quote {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 3rem;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 2.5rem 0.5rem;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 80%;
}

.quotebg {
  opacity: 0.1;
  position: absolute;
  height: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="quotebox">
  <img class="quotebg" src="images/quotes.svg" alt="" />
  <blockquote class="quote">
    Neque id lacus, fringilla diam urna. Interdum facilisi aenean quis maecenas suspendisse maecenas orci.
  </blockquote>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide `images/quotes.svg`?

Comment: How do I attach an svg file to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `transform : translateX()`, the great thing about translate is that it will always move according to your element even if it uses `position:aboslute`, whereas left or right property will use the percentage of the relative parent element.

Also don't forget to set `.quotebox` to relative to keep your element inside its parent.

```
.quotebox {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 70%;
}

.quote {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 3rem;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 2.5rem 0.5rem;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 80%;
}

.quotebg {
  opacity: 0.1;
  position: absolute;
  height: 20%;
  transform: translateX(-50%); // negative value to move to the left, positive to the right
}
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Just needed to add an overflow: hidden to .quotebox and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `left` value to move the image like this:

```css
.quotebox {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 70%;
}

.quote {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 3rem;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 2.5rem 0.5rem;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 80%;
}

.quotebg {
  opacity: 0.1;
  position: absolute;
  height: 20%;
  left:20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="quotebox">
  <img class="quotebg" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/hix5K.png" alt="" />
  <blockquote class="quote">
    Neque id lacus, fringilla diam urna. Interdum facilisi aenean quis maecenas suspendisse maecenas orci.
  </blockquote>
</div>
```

Comment: No, that literally made no difference.

Comment: @MarkOglesby sorry to hear that, it worked in the snippet perhaps it's something else